# Fetching standart IOS strings localizations from simulator

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I wondering is it a way to fetch translations for standard strings that are already in iOS.
Or directly access to their dictionary.
For instance when you swiping to delete cell in table view, there is a string which is Delete for english Smazat for czech and so on.
So is it a way to get this string directly or, may be fetch is somehow for latter usage.